# I can't get PUT data in PHP from jQuery Ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request, put

When I try to access the form data I send with a jQuery AJAX **PUT** request, I get this response:

> Array (
> [------WebKitFormBoundary4TPPQZu7B7WFrUsv Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "id" 7
> ------WebKitFormBoundary4TPPQZu7B7WFrUsv Content-Disposition: form-data; name="naam" Eiusmod alias est do
> ------WebKitFormBoundary4TPPQZu7B7WFrUsv Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email" zatapohopu@mailinator.com
> ------WebKitFormBoundary4TPPQZu7B7WFrUsv Content-Disposition: form-data; name="adres" Voluptates adipisici
> ------WebKitFormBoundary4TPPQZu7B7WFrUsv Content-Disposition: form-data; name="telefoonnummer" 0612345678
> ------WebKitFormBoundary4TPPQZu7B7WFrUsv Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rol" 4
> ------WebKitFormBoundary4TPPQZu7B7WFrUsv-- ) 
>  **Warning**:  Undefined array key "id" in
> **C:\xampp\htdocs\P08\hoornhek\api\gebruiker.php** on line
> **22**

I also can't get the array keys.
This is my jQuery AJAX request:

```
$('#bewerkGebruikerForm').on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData(this);

            // Opslaan gegevens gebruiker
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/P08/hoornhek/api/gebruiker.php',
                type: 'put',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    if(response['success']) {
                        $('#bewerkGebruikerModal').hide();
                        window.location.reload();
                    } else {
                        showErrors(response.errors);
                    }
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    showErrors(error.errors);
                }
            });
        });
```

And this is my PHP (API) code:

```
$requestMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
switch ($requestMethod) {
    case "GET":
        getGebruiker();
    case "POST":
        createGebruiker();
        break;
    case "PUT":
        parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_PUT);

        print_r($_PUT);
        echo $_PUT['id'];

        updateGebruiker();
        break;
    case "DELETE":
        parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_DELETE);
        deleteGebruiker();
        break;
    default:
        exit();
}
```

For my GET, POST and DELETE requests everything works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant access the data from a PUT request via $_REQUEST. You'd need something like:

```
case "PUT":
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $sent_vars);

    echo json_encode(['response'=>$sent_vars['id']]); // use an array and json_encode toavoid messy string concatenation

    updateGebruiker();
    break;
```

See also [Accessing Incoming PUT Data from PHP](https://lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php)